# How do I share MySQL database project?

Tags: mysql

I need to send my MySQL project to my Colleague.
I tried the following:

1. Save Script, which creates a file of 1KB which has no content but the latest query.
2. Export via Server > Data Export which gives me a file looking like this:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

How do I create a dump which actually works ?

EDIT: There is no content/values but just this. I cannot run this result as a query and cannot create tables with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a dump that "actually works". The comments are there so that if loading into an older version of MySQL it doesn't junk things up, the preamble is the version of MySQL required to enable that statement, in this case 4.1.1.

These can be produced with `mysqldump`, MySQL Workbench, or other tools which use the same system.

Don't worry about that unless it's causing issues, and if it is, include the *exact* issue you're having.

Generally you'll want to export from version X and import to version >= X, but loading into an older version usually works because of that system.

Comment: So another person with another local host can open that file? I somehow no got the DDL for one of 6 tables. I really don't understand why it doesn't simply give me all six.

Comment: `mysqldump` is compatible with both MySQL Workbench and the `mysql` command-line client.